# Aligning 2 html.Divs of text next to each other in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to place 2 Div elements side by side, without luck. I have been following
https://community.plotly.com/t/horizontally-stack-components/10806 and
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dash-for-beginners-dash-plotly-python-fcd1fe02b749 guides on using width<50% and 'display': 'inline-block' but without luck.

If you look at attached pictures, it looks like the block that is supposed to go to the right, actually does, until i update the page by choosing a song in the list to show the lyrics on the left, then it pushes the recommendations to the bottom. Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```py
html.Div([
            html.Div(id="lyrics",style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
            html.Div([
            html.H6(id="recommendations",children="Recommendations:"),
            html.H3(id="songsbysameartist",children='Songs by the same artist:',
                    ),
            html.H6(id="sameartistrecommendations",
                    ),
            html.H3(id="songsfromotherartists",children='Music from other artists that you might also like:',
                   ),
            html.H6(id="otherartistrecommendations",
                )
            ],
            style = {'width': '30%', 'display': 'inline-block'})
            ])
```

edited code would look like this:

```py
html.Div([
            html.Div(id="lyrics",style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
            html.Div([
            html.H6(id="recommendations",children="Recommendations:"),
            html.H3(id="songsbysameartist",children='Songs by the same artist:',
                    ),
            html.H6(id="sameartistrecommendations",
                    ),
            html.H3(id="songsfromotherartists",children='Music from other artists that you might also like:',
                   ),
            html.H6(id="otherartistrecommendations",
                )
            ],
            style = {'width': '30%', 'display': 'flex'})
            ])
```

since the bottom style is connected to the parent Div above recommendations as far as I can tell.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using [dash-bootstrap-components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/)? Here you can use rows and columns to arange your content in a layout fitting to your needs.

Comment: Also using `display: flex` for the parent div should do the job just fine.

Comment: @MrLeeh I havent considered it actually, does it also include dropdowns and so on with the same functionality? I have already made it all in Core components so I would rather make it work with that :D, Tried display: flex, but its not working sadly. With display: flex it just puts the whole recommendation block on the left at all times

Comment: Can you post the code with display: flex? It is important to apply it to the parents. The children should not have a display property.

Comment: @MrLeeh Yes sir, i added an edited piece of code to the main document now :-)

Comment: That doesn't look right. The style attribute goes between the curvy brackets:

`html.Div([...], style={"display": "flex"})`
Otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: @MrLeeh the curly bracket in the end of style refers back to one started at `
html.Div([
`
, so i believe it is exactly like you just wrote it, namely, after the square brackets including the children and between the curly brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

I believe the error is in the structure. Parent Div needs to have `"display":"flex"` while the 2 children Div elements have `"display":"inline-block"`.

Correct code ended up like this:

```py
html.Div([
                    html.Div([
                        html.Div(id="songandartist",style={'display': 'flex',"fontSize" : 40,"marginBottom":50}),
                        html.Div(id="lyrics",style={'display': 'flex'}
                        )
                    ],style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                    html.Div([
                        html.Div(id="recommendations",children="Recommendations:",style={"fontSize" : 40,"marginBottom":50,'display': 'flex'}),
                        html.Div(id="songsbysameartist",style={"fontSize" : 27,'display':'flex'},children='Songs by the same artist:',
                        ),
                        html.Div(id="sameartistrecommendations",style={"marginBottom":50,'whiteSpace': 'pre-line','display': 'flex'}
                        ),
                        html.Div(id="songsfromotherartists",style={"fontSize" : 27,'display': 'flex'},children='Music from other artists that you might also like:',
                       ),
                        html.Div(id="otherartistrecommendations",style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line','display': 'flex'}
                    )
                    ],
                style = {'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'})
                ],style={"display": "flex"})
```